# validating IP in bash, CentOS

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Trying to write validation but something is wrong,

```
function valid_ip(){
  ip=$1
  if [ $ip =~ ^$regx\.$regx\.$regx\.$regx$ ]; then 
    return 0 
  else 
    return 1 
  fi
}
```

I believe it is a minor mistake I'm making but can't catch it..

Comment: I don't see any errors here.  Or a question.  Or a value for `regx`.

Comment: . . . or a definition of the `$regex` ... Please update your Q with needed info. Good luck. (I didn't downvote).

Comment: for starters, to use regular expressions in bash you need to use `[[ ... ]]`, not `[ ... ]`

Comment: No probs shellter , cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you have some values for `regx` and presumably you are having some sort of IP list

```
function valid_ip(){
  ip=$1
  if [[ $ip =~ ^$regx\.$regx\.$regx\.$regx$ ]]; then 
    return 0 
  else 
    return 1 
  fi
}
```